# iOS: Delegate setup

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have 3 `Scenes` connected via `Segue`.

`SceneA` > `SceneB` > `SceneC`

`SceneA` calls `SceneB`, and `SceneB` calls `SceneC`.  You can't get to `SceneC` from `SceneA` without going through `SceneB`.

I want `SceneA` to be a `delegate` for `SceneC`.

I'm thinking I have to setup `SceneA` as a `SceneB` delegate, and setup `SceneB` as `SceneC Delegate`.

I really don't need `SceneB` to be `SceneC`'s delegate.  Is there a  way I can directly setup `SceneA` as `SceneC`'s delegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go through `SceneB` by the sounds of your setup, but `SceneA` doesn't need to be the `delegate` of `SceneB`. You can pass information to `SceneB` that it won't directly use other than to pass on to `SceneC` when the segue is triggered. Just name the property on `SceneB` appropriately so it's obvious what it's being used for.

Comment: Thanks. "..that it won't directly use other than to pass on to SceneC"  Do you mean other than to pass on to SceneA ?

Comment: Also, you can please elaborate on: Just name the property on SceneB appropriately so it's obvious what it's being used for.  With an example?

Comment: `SceneA` passes itself to `SceneB` during the segue. `SceneB` holds the instance in a property named `sceneCDelegate`. `SceneB` passes `sceneCDelegate` to `SceneC` during the segue.

Comment: The delegate will Dismiss SceneB & C, and trigger another Segue.  By holding it in a property, Can I still dismiss Scene B & C and call A again?

Comment: If you are dismissing B & C, you don't need to reshow A, that should be automatic. How are your segues presenting (push or modal)? You probably should not be using modals...

Answer (score 2):

You can have reference of A in B, when you will create C in B set its delegate to A. Like this.
in A when you create B set property value i.e b.aObj = self;. When in B you are creating C set c.delegate = aObj;

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Wain, but another approach would be to post notifications from `SceneC` that `SceneA` is listening for. This results in a disconnected behavior which is not always ideal, but it's something to consider without knowing your intentions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using -`[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]` and -`[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:]`.
If you don't want your delegate to return a value it's the best decision. If you want your delegate to return a value, do like @Wain suggested.